# Persisting view state in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I've got large Swing application with more than 50 views (forms, dialogs, menus, popups, etc..). What I need is some intelligent way of persisting view states and bringing them back to life. There are lots of tables, splitters, check boxes and other visual elements which users would want to have preserved. Of course I'd be able to do this manually.. but on such a scale it would be a monstrously tedious coding and bugs all around the place.

The question:
Is there any framework, library or a product which does this without too much hassle? The problem sounds to be pretty common place, so I'd rather find something solid instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: B/SAF supports saving view state - unfortunately not very actively maintained. You might get some ideas of how to do it, though. Basically, the way they do it is to have per-component type persistable state type which can save/load the properties as needed and persist those via xmlDe/Encoder

Comment: +1 for Better Swing Application Framework, I will look into that, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First, separate your data (model) from your Swing components (view)

Once you have a complete data model, you can use an XML generator / XML parser to save and restore your data model, respectively.  You can use a relational database to save and restore your data model.  Whatever makes the most sense for the amount of data in your model.

I have an example of a Java Swing model and a view in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423696/restart-replay-java-game-without-restarting-the-gui/13423840#13423840).

Edited to add: One of Dima's assertions is *Take for example a JTable with 20 columns 5 of which user made visible while hiding others and also making columns of a certain width.*

Fine.  The TableModel, column visibility booleans, and column width integers or doubles had better be somewhere in your model.

Follow the link to my other answer and see that my GUI state data is part of the model.

Comment: Data models are separate, but not everything in the app is based on data models, there a visual aspects which aren't. Take for example a JTable with 20 columns 5 of which user made visible while hiding others and also making columns of a certain width. Or a split view arranged in a certain way. As I said, manual persistence is my last rescue. I am after a tool which already does this in order to bypass the coding labor and adding new bugs to an old problem.

Comment: @Dima: See my updated answer.  GUI state data is still data that belongs in your model.

Comment: So you are suggesting to manually create additional set of models (to those which actually hold business stuff) and persist them into some store. I sought for something less laborious. For example, a swing component state could probably be serialized in bulk and then restored. Another example is look and feel. I don't go and introduce new set of models, I simply switch the library which does the hard job. Such library I am after.

Comment: @dima sterilisation of swing components is no longer recommended. Because some of your requirements are based on (what appears to be) custom solutions (there is no default column hiding solution in Swing tables), any "default" solution is going to fall short.  In the end your going to need to get your hands dirty and meals describes about how each element is to be saved

Comment: -1 for storing view state in the data model: what diametrical opposite of what the models are designed for. Doing so would f.i. prevent sharing the model across different views.

Comment: @kleopatra: I disagree.  You must store state in the data model if you want the ability to restart.  However, the GUI state data and the business data should certainly live in different classes, so you can share the business data model.

Comment: I am totally agree with kleopatra on this. Storing view stuff in data model is wrong and not practical, at least in my case where models are pure business representation of the data. Last thing I want is to stick view stuff into there. It also contradicts basic MVC pattern principals and will not work in real life applications. But I do agree that it's OK for a one time workaround solution.