# Issue Repainting/Updating a JPanel in a Separate Class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm working on a Java assignment and I've created a JFrame applet that has four panels created in separate classes which are returned to the main class and added to the main panel.
The issue I'm facing is that my south panel has a combo box in it.  Based off the selection from that combobox I'd like to have one or more of the other panels updated based off that selection.  I'm not sure how to accomplish this and I've looked into repainting that single panel or even recreating the entire main panel.
Any help and/or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I've posted the code below from the main panel class for starters.

I'm a first time poster here so if there isn't enough detail or I've left something out please let me know.

```
public class Main_GUI_Panel extends JFrame {

    public static Panel_North northPanel;
    public static Panel_Center centerPanel;
    public static Panel_West westPanel;
    public static Panel_South southPanel;
    private int index = -1;

    public Main_GUI_Panel() {
        super("Java 2: Final Project");
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK); //set the applet background color
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());  //set the Layout for the applet

        //START - call methods to create & set panels
            northPanel = new Panel_North();
            westPanel = new Panel_West();
            centerPanel = new Panel_Center();
            southPanel = new Panel_South();

            add(northPanel.setNorth(),BorderLayout.NORTH); //set the North portion of the applet
            add(westPanel.setWest(index),BorderLayout.WEST); //set the West portion of the applet
            add(centerPanel.setCenter(),BorderLayout.CENTER); //set the Center portion of the applet
            add(southPanel.setSouth(),BorderLayout.SOUTH); //set the South portion of the applet
        //END - call methods to set panels
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a GUI, you should (must) create one or more model classes that hold the data for your GUI.  This is the model.  Your GUI components are the view.  These parts make up the model / view / controller (MVC) of your application.

You pass an instance of the top level model class to all the panels of your GUI.  Each panel can update the model class, and in turn, the panels get their data from the model.

So, what you do in one panel can effect the display of a different panel.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423696/restart-replay-java-game-without-restarting-the-gui/13423840#13423840) goes into more detail about a GUI model and a GUI view.

Comment: I looked at the detail link that you provided and this helps me get a better understanding of what I'm after.  I'm still having issues getting the solution to work.

Since my Main_GUI_Panel creates each panel as an object and then calls the method to initially create each panel and return it to the Main_GUI_Panel to be added, would the removal of say the westPanel happen in a separate method within class Panel_West or would that be in a separate method within Main_GUI_Panel which would then call a new method in Panel_West to create the new/updated panel?

Comment: @user1895061: I think you're talking about adding and removing GUI components.  If so, this code would belong in the Main_GUI_Panel.  The creation of a component belongs in the component's constructor.  Removing a component doesn't destroy the component.  If you want to have more than one west panel, create all of the west panels, and add the one you want to display and remove the others in the Main_GUI_Panel.